# Scroll horizontally inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to implement a horizontal scroll inside a div. It works as expected in smaller screen. For large screen(desktop), the div contents appends to another line. How to avoid this.?

HTML:

```
  <body>
<div class="container-fluid" id="scrollquestion" style="overflow-x:scroll;white-space: nowrap;overflow-y:hidden ;top: 500px; padding: 4px; width:auto;">

    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6>2</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6>3</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6>4</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6>5</h6>

    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6>5</h6>

    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6>5</h6>

    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div><div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div><div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div><div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div><div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div><div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>

</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

CSS :

```
.col-sm-3{display: inline-block;width:auto;}
.c {
   color: #64cbcd;
   font-size: 11px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 40px;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   border-color: blue;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #002525; // JUST ADD THIS LINE AND MODIFY YOUR COLOR
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right:10px
}
```

For smaller screen, it works as expected. Check : https://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/jeoh5220/2/

In desktop, it comes as the following image.
[image: Image for desktop]

Comment: Doesn't wrap for me on desktop Chrome 41.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/jeoh5220/2/ your fiddle had no libraries added check the updated one.

Comment: It is working fine for chrome 44.

Comment: I was unable to see a wrap in this example and I've tried with IE 11, Chrome 44 and Firefox 29. Could you precise which browser let you display that ?

Comment: able to reproduce it .. Please look it on full screen .. On Jsfiddle link you will not able to reproduce it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and most important why you are using '.col-sm-3' class of bootstrap if you don't want to use its properties and now answer to your question 'float:left' property of '.col-sm-3' is messing it up. Simply, overwrite it and problem will get resolved.

```
.c {
   float:none;
}
```

Or remove col-sm-3 from HTML

That't it :)

Comment: Awesome .. which method you have used then ? float:none or removing class from HTML ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Give `white-space: nowrap` for `.c`:

```
.c {
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added height to container and it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

its not possible through css, use jquery, find children width and apply it

```
var width = 0;
$('.c').each(function() {
    width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
});
$('.horizontal-scroll').css('width', width+100);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jeoh5220/3/)